# Disparity error in active light stereo systems?

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

[image]

Based on this relationship, if we have to estimate the 'disparity error' of a stereo system which uses active light on the scene - can we estimate the disparity error to be very small? According to [this](http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/eval3/) the best performing algorithms have a sub-pixel disparity error, so can we assume using a structured / active light source in these cases to facilitate stereo-matching will result in reduced disparity error?